# Permissions issues again

Tags: permissions, files

Last few months, I have run into one after another issue on permissions. Operating systems have been Mint, Ubuntu Gnome, and now Ubuntu Studio. I have replaced hard drives, and all internal components, including motherboard and cpu last week.

After copying files from an external NTFS hard drive back onto my internal hard drive last night, I noticed some files that I did not need or want had been copied into my "Documents" folder. Some of these are Windows .exe files. And some are simply photos. (.png and .dng files seem to be especially susceptible to permissions issues.)

I went to delete them and I got the message that I have learned to hate. I did not have permissions to do this. In checking, I see that permissions are now assigned to "Root" for the files in question. And in trying to change these, It appears that I do not have "Root" permissions to change them...

The permissions issue does not relate to the drive, this time. But only to the files in question.

While I have some seriously unflattering words about these permissions issues, how can I get my permissions back?

Comment: If root owns the files, only root can change the permissions; use `sudo`.

Comment: sudo. – fkraiem  Responce: "command not found"

Comment: Any variation of "fkraiem" results in command not found. And I am unaware of this command either.

Comment: Getting my permissions back is a problem. But why this is continually happening is a bigger problem. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Also, as I understand it, NTFS files systems do not store permissions. So when they are copied to an EXT4 System drive, they should have no permissions assigned to them.  And .exe Windows files really should have no permissions assigned to them. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: @lloyd So you actually ran `sudo. – fkraiem` in terminal?! o.O `fkraiem` is not a command, it's just the other user's nickname on this site (just like "lloyd" is yours).

Comment: I did a copy and paste since I did not recognize it. Command Not Recognized was the response.  In any case, I got the job done using 'Chmod 777 -R /(folders)

Answer (score 0):

I got the job done using 'Chmod 777 -R /(folders)'

I still do not know why this continues to happen. Permissions on files, folders, and drives get changed to "ROOT" for no reason...

Sometimes my solution works. And sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I noticed my old post and thought I would get back to it. This seems to be a reoccurring problem and is caused, at least in some cases, by backup software changing permissions on the computer to 'ROOT' only for ALL 'Read' & 'Write', with the exception of my home directory. Changing the permissions for 'Others' seems to be the only reliable solution. Otherwise other software on my computer stops working. This even includes 'Ubuntu Update' for software. Also my many USB drives either become corrupted or simply become useless. I have ended up fixing this several times now, but am still surprised.